# sort series with pandas in python

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I selected one column from the a DataFrame, then I got a Series. How can I sort the series? I used the Series.sort(), but it doesn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,0,3,8],
                    'B': ['B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11']})
df

    A   B
0   5   B8
1   0   B9
2   3   B10
3   8   B11
```

Then I selected the column 'A'

```
df['A']

    A
 0  5
 1  0
 2  3
 3  8
```

After selected 'A' column, I got a Series, but with Series.sort(), it doesn't work.

```
df['A'].sort()
```

It shows the error:

"ValueError: This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy"

So I used the Series.copy() function to copy the series, after that I sort the series, but there is no outcome.

```
df['A'].copy().sort()
```

But there is no result returned.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? does `df['A'].sort_values()` work?

Comment: Hi @EdChum, I use the 0.16.2 version, but the sort_values() looks like also deprecated.

Comment: `sort_values` is the new method, `sort` is deprecated in later versions so be aware of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But there is no result returned.

That is because the sort is in place, it modifies the object. Try this

```
A = df['A'].copy()
A.sort()
print(A)
```

Answer (score 5):

One of them will work for you -

```
df.sort('A',ascending=False,inplace=True)  #old version
df.sort_values('A',ascending=False,inplace=True) #new version
```

Comment: great answer @shikha

Answer (score 0):

Since the `sort()` function is deprecated, one must use the `sort_values(inplace=True)` for inplace sorting instead ([source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)).

So the code should look like this:

```
A = df['A'].copy()
A.sort_values(inplace=True)
```